# Getting multiple maxes of summed values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Consider this sample data:

```
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| username | qnum | qvalue | date            |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Linda    | 1    | 2      | 11/14/2017 7:25 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Fred     | 1    | 1      | 11/23/2017 7:59 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Brian    | 5    | 2      | 11/17/2017 7:25 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Sandra   | 6    | 1      | 11/25/2017 7:26 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Tom      | 6    | 1      | 11/22/2017 7:32 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Paul     | 6    | 1      | 11/22/2017 7:36 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Andrew   | 7    | 2      | 11/23/2017 7:37 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Luke     | 3    | 1      | 11/23/2017 8:03 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| William  | 8    | 1      | 11/23/2017 8:03 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Linda    | 9    | 2      | 11/15/2017 8:03 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Brian    | 3    | 2      | 11/17/2017 8:04 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Joan     | 9    | 1      | 11/23/2017 8:04 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Chris    | 8    | 1      | 11/23/2017 8:04 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
| Kim      | 8    | 1      | 11/15/2017 8:04 |
+----------+------+--------+-----------------+
```

I am attempting to get the person who has the highest sum of qvalue for last week.  I am able to get this information with the following SQL but my problem is that if more than one user has the top score then it does not show both of their names because I am using the LIMIT function.  Is there a way to use max and sum together to get the desired result?  The desired result would be a result set with both Linda and Brian listed because last week they both had a sum score of 4 and were tied.

```
SELECT username, SUM(qvalue) AS score FROM trivia_scoreboard 
WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY AND `date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is the version of MariaDB? The latest one supports CTE.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max for efficient ways to get groupwise max with and without dups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to join that query with a query that gets everyone's total.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT username, SUM(qvalue) AS score FROM trivia_scoreboard 
    WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY AND `date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
    GROUP BY username
) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(qvalue) AS score FROM trivia_scoreboard 
    WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY AND `date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
    GROUP BY username
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS t2 ON t1.score = t2.score
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89e7d/1)

Comment: There's no need for ORDER BY in the first subquery. However I would Just use a HAVING clause instead of the JOIN.

Comment: Got rid of the `ORDER BY`, but not sure how to use `HAVING` for this. You can't say `HAVING score = MAX(score)`

Comment: `having score = (original query without username with LIMIT 1)` - like in Gordons answer. But I'd be fine with both of the answers.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't think MySQL allows `LIMIT` when you use a subquery in a comparison like that.

Comment: I've used that a lot even in the WHERE clause :-) .. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89e7d/5

Comment: Ahh, it's only in `WHERE xxx IN (SELECT...)` that it's not allowed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810346/alternative-to-using-limit-keyword-in-a-subquery-in-mysql Well, I just get in the habit of using joins, they work better for lots of things in MySQL.

Comment: Caution:  The construct `FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ..` does becomes quite slow if the tables are big.

Comment: @RickJames true, although notice that the subqueries being joined are the result of grouping, so they'll be much smaller than the original tables. And the second subquery returns just a single row, so it's not a big cross product. The only problem is if doing the grouping is expensive -- then it might be necessary to do that into a temporary table (necessary to make up for MySQL's lack of CTE).

Comment: @Barmar - I wonder if the Optimizer is smart enough to realize that one subquery has only one row and do that one first.  MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2 have CTEs; I wonder if their Optimizers are smart here.

Comment: More impressive would be if the optimizer realizes that the subqueries are the same except for `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, so it does it once like a CTE and reuses the temporary table.

Answer (score 3):

You can also phrase this using `having`:

```
SELECT ts.username, SUM(ts.qvalue) AS score
FROM trivia_scoreboard fs
WHERE ts.`date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY AND 
      ts.`date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
GROUP BY username
HAVING score = (SELECT SUM(ts2.qvalue) as score
                FROM trivia_scoreboard ts2
                WHERE ts2.`date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY AND 
                      ts2.`date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
                GROUP BY username
                ORDER BY score DESC
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

The difference between this and the version using `join` is really a matter of taste.  This might have slightly better performance, because of details about how aggregations scale on larger amounts of data.

Comment: This answer also solves my problem, I accepted Barmar's answer only because he answered first.

Comment: @Tibblez . . . I upvoted Barmar's because it is just as correct.  There may be some circumstances where one version would be preferred over the other.

Comment: No need for `ORDER BY score DESC` at the end, since everyone has the same score (I mistakenly kept that in my original answer, too).

Comment: I'd like to hope that our two queries would produce the same execution plan, but the ways of MySQL are mysterious. :)

Comment: @Barmar . . . Actually, I think you are right in this case.