# remove all rows except the last 10 rows? Or max number of rows = 10?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a small question. Is it possible if you have a database, that you can keep only the last 10 records inserted in the table? Or that your table can only hold 10 records, so when a new record is inserted, it adds it but gets rid of the last inserted record?

I'm using mySQL and PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: At least in MySQL you can not delete rows from a table in a trigger for the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, using a trigger.

I don't think I recommend actually doing this.  There is overhead to deleting records.  Instead, you can just create a view such as:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*
    from t
    order by insertionDateTime desc
    limit 10;
```

This might seem expensive, but with an index on `(insertionDateTime desc)`, the performance should be reasonable.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Was already using limit=10 , but i was just scared that it might be bad filling the database up while i only actually display 10 records.

Comment: @ArthurRobaeys . . . Remember the index!  If this does really get to be big (like millions of rows), you might want to schedule a job to remove older values, if you are sure you won't ever need them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

`delete from my_table where id not in (select id from my_table order by id desc limit 10);`

Assuming `id` is a number field that is incremented on each insert. Timestamps would also work.

Comment: MySQL didn't support LIMIT for IN subqueries? Did they fix that in any version?

Comment: You're right. I didn't have mysql handy when answering and forgot. Here's how to work around that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810346/alternative-to-using-limit-keyword-in-a-subquery-in-mysql