# Get only 3 rows from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get only three rows from the joined table.
For example, I have a categories table. I want to get popular categories and 3 articles from these categories without using SQL inside loop. Total post count should be 12.

I tried this but didn't work. (If I set `limit 1` it works. But not working on `limit 3`)

```
SELECT 
    categories.name AS cname,
    categories.url  AS curl,
    articles.name,
    articles.url,
    articles.image
FROM   
    categories
    JOIN articles ON articles.id = (
        SELECT p.id
        FROM articles AS p
        WHERE categories.id = p.category AND p.delete = '0'
        ORDER  BY p.id DESC
        LIMIT  3
    )
WHERE  
    categories.delete = '0'
    AND categories.popular = '1'
```

Comment: replace your syntax  **JOIN articles ON articles.id = (** with **JOIN articles ON articles.id IN (**

Comment: not worked for me :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to using LIMIT keyword in a SubQuery in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810346/alternative-to-using-limit-keyword-in-a-subquery-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8+, you would simply do:

```
SELECT c.name AS cname, c.url  AS curl,
       a.name, a.url, a.image
FROM categories c JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.category ORDER BY a.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM articles a
      WHERE a.delete = 0
     ) a
     ON a.category = c.id
WHERE a.seqnum <= 3 AND
      c.delete = 0 AND
      c.popular = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery returns multiple records (actually 3), so the equality operator should be replaced with the `IN` operator.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    categories.name AS cname,
    categories.url  AS curl,
    articles.name,
    articles.url,
    articles.image
FROM   
    categories
    JOIN articles ON articles.id IN (
        SELECT p.id
        FROM articles AS p
        WHERE categories.id = p.category AND p.delete = '0'
        ORDER  BY p.id DESC
        LIMIT  3
    )
WHERE  
    categories.delete = '0'
    AND categories.popular = '1'
```

Comment: i get this error in phpmyadmin: 
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @Cihan: which version of MySQL are you using?