# Getting just the last "batch" of values in SQL

Tags: sql

Considering a table with:

```
common_id     id     result 
10            1      8
10            2      10
10            3      4
10            1      7
10            2      5
10            3      2
```

I want **just** the last "batch" -- in this case, the last 3 results - but the number of ids in the batch can be different each time (*per a certain `common_id`). You **can assume** that each "batch" has the **same** ids, their order might be different though. So a "batch" is a series of ids that ends with a row having an id that already appeared (again, a batch is per a `common_id`).

What query can achieve this?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last" batch unless you have a column that contains the ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A set implies distinct members. An SQL table doesn't require rows to be distinct, right?

Comment: so I'll have to use another "`batch_id`" column...?

Comment: @nicomp - multiset rather than set

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (which may be useful to others);

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742417/522169), what I did was add a new column, which we'll call `batch_id` - it has the same unique number for all rows in a "batch" and it's always in incrementing order.

E.g.:

```
common_id     id     result    batch_id
10            1      8         1
10            2      10        1
10            3      4         1
10            1      7         2
10            2      5         2
10            3      2         2
```

The query to get just the rows of the "latest batch" is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT batch_id
    FROM table
    WHERE common_id = 10
    ORDER BY batch_id DESC LIMIT 1
) latest
ON table.batch_id
IN (latest.batch_id)
```